# The time suits me well or fits me well?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which is better to refer to the time, saying that it suits me well or that it fits me well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would say "The time suits me well."

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suit):

> Suit *(verb)*
>
> : to provide what is required or wanted by or for (someone or something)
>
> : to be proper or suitable for (someone or something)
>
> : to be attractive on (someone)

When you say that a certain time suits you well, you're saying that that time is suitable for you.

On the other hand, if you say something *fits you well*, you're either literally talking about clothing that fits your body, or you're figurative talking about a trait that "fits" you or seems like it could be applied to you. A Google search of "fits me well" brings back results to this effect, for example ["This shoe fits me well"](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/676775) (This shoe fits my foot well) and ["I think this offense fits me well"](http://www.csnwashington.com/redskinsblog/mccoy-i-think-offense-fits-me-well-video) (This position fits the skills that I have).